# Add a symbol before any letter

Tags: awk

I have a text file with each line having some defined number of fields but they can differ from line to line. All I want to do is to add "=" sign in front of every value in the field in that line.

For example
INPUT FILE

```
A   B   C   D   E
P   Q   R   S   T   U
L   M   N   O
```

OUTPUT FILE

```
=A  =B  =C  =D  =E
=P  =Q  =R  =S  =T  =U
=L  =M  =N  =O
```

Also this is just an example, my file contains some lines where number of field are more than 20. How to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this in `awk`, you could use:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "=%s ",$i;printf "\n"}' filename
```

Loop over the internal `NF` (number of fields) variable, printing each field with an equals prepended and a space appended, then after printing all fields, print a newline.

Comment: Hi this works. Thanks a lot. Can you tell why printf is used and not print???

Comment: `print` adds a newline by default, `printf` does not

Comment: Note that it changes the spacing of the fields.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your fields contain more than just one letter, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/\</=/g' <<END
foo    bar    baz
A      B      C
apple  banana cherry
END
```

```
=foo    =bar    =baz
=A      =B      =C
=apple  =banana =cherry
```

GNU sed's `\<` regex construct is a zero-width "start of word" marker (the transition between a non-word (or the beginning of the line) and a word character (alnums in your locale or underscore)). So we're replacing the start of each *word* with the "=" character.

(sed regex reference [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html#Regular-expression-syntaxes))

Comment: Tangentially, I wonder why Perl's regex syntax does not have "start of word" and "end of word" markers.

Comment: Maybe `\b\w` for work around.

Comment: good idea. `\b(?=\w)` would be more exact. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to update my comment, I used `\b(?=\w)` in my answer :)

Comment: Though `\<` originated in BSDs (`ex`/`grep`), it seems it never made it to any BSD `sed`. It is in GNU `sed` though. It's not POSIX.

Answer (score 5):

A shorter `awk` version:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/([^ ]+)/,"=&",$0)' file
=A   =B   =C   =D   =E
=P   =Q   =R   =S   =T   =U
=L   =M   =N   =O
```

**Explanation**

We do a global substitution for each input line:

- `/([^ ]+)/`: matchs each fields, because fields is separate by spaces, so this regex match all thing except spaces.
- `"=&"`: with each fields, add `=` before it.

`&` meaning is replaced with character that was matched. From `man awk`:

```
gsub(r, s [, t])        For each substring matching the regular expres‐
                        sion  r  in the string t, substitute the string
                        s, and return the number of substitutions.   If
                        t  is  not  supplied,  use  $0.   An  &  in the
                        replacement text is replaced with the text that
                        was  actually matched.  Use \& to get a literal
                        &.  (This must be typed  as  "\\&";  see  GAWK:
                        Effective  AWK Programming for a fuller discus‐
                        sion of the rules for &'s  and  backslashes  in
                        the replacement text of sub(), gsub(), and gen‐
                        sub().)
```

**Update**

For @glenn jackman's answer and comment, I add an equivalent version in `perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\b(?=\w)/=$&/g' file
=A   =B   =C   =D   =E
=P   =Q   =R   =S   =T   =U
=L   =M   =N   =O
```

Comment: Note that the `awk` one removes the blank lines.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: `awk 'NF > 0 {gsub(/([^ ]+)/,"=&",$0)}{print}'` will keep blank lines.

Comment: Or just `awk '{gsub(/([^ ]+)/,"=&");print}'`, or `awk '1+gsub(/([^ ]+)/,"=&")'`,it's just that you were using the result of gsub as a condition to print.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Maybe I think a complicated way. Thanks for good point.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not very clear.

To insert `=` before each sequence of letters, that would be:

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]\{1,\}/=&/g'
```

Before any letter:

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]/=&/g'
```

Before each sequence of non-blanks:

```
sed 's/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}/=&/g'
```

(those are POSIX and portable).

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple sed command,

```
sed 's/\([A-Za-z]\+\)/=\1/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ (echo 'A   B   C'; echo 'A C D F') | sed 's/\([A-Za-z]\+\)/=\1/g'
=A   =B   =C
=A =C =D =F
```

This command will place `=` sign before `A-Z`,`a-z`.

**OR**

try this command also,

```
sed 's/\([ ]\+\)/\1=/g; s/^\(.*\)$/=\1/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ (echo 'A   B   C'; echo 'A C D F') | sed 's/\([ ]\+\)/\1=/g; s/^\(.*\)$/=\1/g'
=A   =B   =C
=A =C =D =F
```

This command will replace one or more spaces with one or more spaces plus `=` sign and also it places `=` on starting.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this a bit with GNU awk

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '{printf "=%s%s", $0,RT}' input.file
=A   =B   =C   =D   =E
=P   =Q   =R   =S   =T   =U
=L   =M   =N   =O
```

Comment: This Works , Can you explain the code? THanks